# Tensorflow cuda,cudart64_101.dll not found

Tags: python, tensorflow

when i import tensorflow i get the warrning message:

```
2020-03-12 17:25:29.372617: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_101.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_101.dll not found
2020-03-12 17:25:29.372953: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
```

When i looked into the  folder of cuda i found `:"cudart64_102.dll"`
i need to use cuda how do i resolve this problem?
I have :

```
tensorflow version 2.1.0
python 3.7.6
cuda_10.2.89
cudnn 7.6.5
```

Comment: will it does,i was just hoping for easier solution because downloading another 2.5 giga file is very time consuming in my country.thank you for your help.

Comment: You need the correct version of CUDA, no way around that..